# Laravel route not found in 8.54.0

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, routes

I'm trying to get a simple ajax request working and all I'm getting is 404 errors. I've followed several tutorials to no avail.

the error I'm getting is: POST http://localhost/AjaxReq 404 (Not Found)

my ajax script on is my main.blade.php at the moment for testing

```
  $.ajax({
              url: '/AjaxReq',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'html',
              contentType:'application/json',
              headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
              data:
              {
                  data1: 'ABC',
                  data2: 'DEF'
              },
              error: function() {alert('Error');},
              success: function(response) {
                          $('#ajaxResponse').empty();
                          $('#ajaxResponse').append(response);
                      }
          });
```

I have this in my web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AjaxController;
```

and

```
Route::post('AjaxReq', [App\Http\Controllers\AjaxController::class, 'ajaxReq'])->name('ajaxReq');
```

my AjaxController.php is just this for now

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    public function ajaxReq(Request $request)
    {

    //
    }
}
```

This is driving me mad, 12 YouTube videos and countless websites and posts on here and every time I get either this error or Controller not found.

Please help.

EDIT: changing to get and going to the page gives a 404, changing the route to your suggestion still 404 and route:list shows POST | AjaxReq | ajaxReq | App\Http\Controllers\AjaxController@ajaxReq | web –

EDIT 2:

ok so i can go to http://localhost/cms/public/AjaxReq with the route get to get and it will run what i put in the controller function but im still getting 404 on the ajax

Comment: change the method to get ```Route::get('AjaxReq'``` in route and the goto http://localhost/AjaxReq via web browser and tell us the output

Comment: make you web.php like this ```Route::post('AjaxReq', [AjaxController::class, 'ajaxReq'])->name('ajaxReq');```

Comment: If you run `artisan route:list`, does the route you're creating even show up in there? You might need to clear the route-cache: `artisan route:clear`

Comment: changing to get and going to the page gives a 404, changing the route to your suggestion still 404 and route:list shows  POST     | AjaxReq                | ajaxReq          | App\Http\Controllers\AjaxController@ajaxReq                            | web

Comment: Also, your ajax content type is set to `application/json` but its sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: If the route that works is `http://localhost/cms/public/AjaxReq` that means the problem is in your Apache setup, not in Laravel. Either point the `DocumentRoot` directly to the `cms/public` or create a new VirtualHost pointing to it.